# Connected to WPA-secured network, but no internet

Tags: 11.04, wireless, internet

My Ubuntu machine can connect to my WPA network, but there's not a trickle of internet to be found. It works fine with another (but farther) WEP network.

Windows system on the WPA network work fine (I'm using one to write this question). Wired connection to the router broadcasting the problematic network is also fine.

Do note that I did not try to connect to network using Windows on the same machine. It's an Atheros card - I will include more details if requested.

Oh and I the other systems on the network are visible as well.

**EDIT** I've removed the Ethernet details from the following output:

```
~$ sudo lshw -class Network

  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR5001 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan2
       version: 01
       serial: 00:22:69:18:f1:d3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath5k driverversion=2.6.38-8-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.2.7 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
       resources: irq:18 memory:55200000-5520ffff
```

Comment: Please add the version of ubuntu you are using together with the exact model of Atheros card - sudo lshw -class Network.  TIA

Comment: @fossfreedom, done!

Comment: maybe suffering from this bug?  There is a suggested solution in the bug report.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/775209

Comment: @fossfreedom, I can view networks and connect fine, just not getting internet connection (IP resolve problem?) and the solution hard codes the network details - I'd rather have Network Manager to manage where I connect.

Answer (score 1):

Good network connection without Internet access could mean that you are behind a proxy server. Check in the working computers if a proxy is set and you can add it in Ubuntu with in System -> Preferences -> "Network Proxy".

To validate if this is your problem, you should be able to ping a website in the terminal using for instance `> ping www.google.com` but the browser will not be able to access to the website.

If the ping fails, then the proxy is probably not your problem. You could then check if you have a DNS server in /etc/resolv.conf and set one if not. I usually test with OpenDNS (208.67.222.222 or 208.67.220.220) when something is not working because it is available most of the time and from anywhere. Set these two addresses in /etc/resolv.conf like this:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

and then try to ping a website again. If ping works but there is still no internet in the browser, then check proxy as described above and add it if necessary.

Hopefully the Internet connection will work after trying this...

Comment: Nope, it ain't no proxy issue, I mess with them (on other computers as well) so I should know.

Comment: And as mentioned have you checked if DNS server was accessible by simply pinging a known working website?

Comment: Yeah, I've pinged Google before as well. And just for the record, it isn't a DNS issue since I can access internet from the other network and both networks connect to the same ISP.

Comment: It could still be a DNS issues because each computer must be well configured with the DNS. So if for some reason your computer does not have the right DNS information it will not be able to ping nor to access websites. Usually the DNS info is passed to your pc along with the DHCP request so if you have a static IP address you will need to set your DNS info in the /etc/resolv.conf file.

Comment: Each? I'm connecting to both networks from the same machine. And did I mention I tried Google DNS as well?

Comment: I thought that the other network meant with some other computer so then I guess you have tried everything. I cannot think about something else to try for now.

Comment: Well, I did mention in the first sentence that on my UBuntu machine there's no internet with WPA but working fine with WEP. Thanks for trying to help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A very recent thread on Ubuntu Forums reported a suggested fix involving three changes to your Natty install:

1. Installing the latest madwifi drivers
2. Blacklisting the existing Ath5k kernel module
3. Using WiCD instead of Network Manager

Follow the step-by-step guide [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1790779) - post #4.