# Connected to network but not to internet, how to make it work?

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, internet, dns

I know there're several post about this and have gone through all of them, but can't really understand how to solve it.

**Problem**
I'm connected to my network but not to the internet. If you do a ping you get this

```
ping: www.google.com: Name or service not known
```

Try this answer and not working: [DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG error in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622470/dns-probe-finished-bad-config-error-in-ubuntu-14-04/622493#622493)

```
/etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc: Warning: /etc/resolv.conf is not a symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`
```

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo resolvconf -u
```

Try using 
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` and getting this error

```
resolvconf-pull-resolved.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
resolvconf-pull-resolved.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
```

The only possible solution I found is this one, but I think is a temporary answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/46036/83345

Have to edit the /etc/resolv.conf and add manually the DNS

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

But I'm afraid the changes will overwritten after the reboot

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

So the question will be, how do I add these DNS permanently, if I reboot this changes will get lost?

Content of /etc/netplan/*.yaml

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
#I add these manually, base in one of the answers but
#getting this error
#sudo netplan apply --debug -Error in network definition: unknown key #'nameservers'nameservers:

nameservers:
  [8.8.8.8, 208.67.222.222,208.67.220.220]
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
# Generated by Connection Manager
nameserver ::1
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: This is a server, yes? Your /etc/resolv.conf doesn't show the local DNS server. Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Ubuntu >= 18.04 then, yes, they will get lost eventually because they get overwritten. Jack Wallen explains this in his [article](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-dns-nameservers-in-ubuntu-server-18-04/), and how you should possibly configure your DNS.

If you have Ubuntu < 18.04 then you can manually edit some of your other settings using `/etc/network/interfaces`

## Recap:

### 18.04

Basically start by modifying your network config files now located at: `/etc/netplan/<<01-99>>-netcfg.yaml`. You'll want to make the appropriate edits to the `.yaml` file like so:

```
...
nameservers:
    [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
...
```

then type: `sudo netplan apply` or `sudo netplan apply --debug` if something goes wrong.

### < 18.04

edit: `/etc/network/interfaces` like so:

```
...
dns-addresses 8.8.4.4,8.8.8.8
...
```

Comment: I supposed that this location: `/etc/netplan/<<01-99>>-netcfg.yaml` will be /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml in my case?

Comment: Try it with the debug flag and getting this error
`/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml:5:1: Error in network definition: unknown key 'nameservers' nameservers:`

Comment: This might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/961552/need-example-netplan-yaml-for-static-ip.  You can also use `netplan --debug generate` to help you discover syntax errors.

Comment: This is what I get sudo netplan --debug apply
** (generate:15050): DEBUG: 19:41:57.807: Processing input file /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml..
** (generate:15050): DEBUG: 19:41:57.807: starting new processing pass
/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml:6:1: Error in network definition: unknown key 'nameservers'
nameservers:
^